# Ruby looping through two objects and checking if something is present in both objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two objects: gateways and messages
I want to check if the contact_id for each gateway in gateways is equal to the contact_id in each message in messages: if the contact_ids are equal, I want to use another field in the gateways object else continue;
I considered doing something like:

```
for gateway in gateways
  for message in messages
    if gateway.contact_id == message.contact_id 
      someRandomArray.push(gateway.files)
    end
  end
end
```

But is there a better way of doing this than the double for loop it looks wrong. Perhaps something with map or select? cannot figure this out no matter how much I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save all the message contact IDs in a set and then loop over the gateways to check if a gateway's contact ID is in that set

```
all_message_contact_ids = Set.new messages.map {|message| message.contact_id}
gateways.each do |gateway|
  if all_message_contact_ids.include? gateway.contact_id
    someRandomArray.push(gateway.files)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
message_contact_ids = messages.map(&:contact_id)
selected_gateways = gateways.select{ |gw| gw.contact_id.in?(message_contact_ids) }
```

Then you can use `selected_gateways` to call whatever fields you like.